# WSO2 ESB scheduled message forwarding processor becomes inactive after reaching max delivery attempt

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I tried to follow this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Guaranteed+Delivery+with+Failover+Message+Store+and+Scheduled+Failover+Message+Forwarding+Processor) , and I did it step by step for four time, for the first 3 times I used WSO2 MB as a broker, and the last time I tried Apache ActiveMQ but the problem is, when I shut down SimpleQuoteService server and send messages to the proxy via SoapUI , they accumulate in my queue and my scheduled message forwarding processor becomes inactivated after reaching max delivery attempts but WSO2-ESB documentation is sayinq : 
"To test the failover scenario, shut down the JMS broker(i.e., the original message store) and send a few messages to the proxy service.
You will see that the messages are not sent to the back-end since the original message store is not available. You will also see that the messages are stored in the failover message store."

Anyone to explain?!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable deactivating the message processor setting "max.delivery.drop" parameter to 'Enabled'. It will drop the message after max delivery attempts without deactivating the processor. See [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Scheduled+Failover+Message+Forwarding+Processor) for docs(definitions) of these parameters.

Comment: Thanks but actually I knew this, is there a way without deactivating message processor and without dropping messages?! for example any integration pattern.

Comment: Do you want to keep trying to delivery until backend comes alive?

Comment: How about setting a very high value to 'max delivery attempts'? Practically if something is failing that much, we can conclude that a drop is fine. WDYT?